# How to have a SoapUI test successfull if SOAFault has a particular message?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

I have a SoapUI test that performs a WSDL call.

This WSDL call is considered a success if either

- response is a valid `SOAPResponse`
- response is a `SOAPFault` with a specific `faultstring`

How can I write a SoapUI test that will be successfull in both cases (and obviously only those cases) ?

**EDIT** my test case already has 3 assertions defined :

- SOAP Response
- Schema compliance
- Not SOAP FAULT

I would like to have something like

- SOAP Response

  - Schema compliance
  - Not SOAP FAULT
- SOAP Fault

  - XPath Match

Comment: Did you have any assertions currently? You can define any number of assertions, say you need 2 assertions as mentioned in your query, and are you concerned that if you defined both assertions, for the same step then one of the assertion will always fail?

Comment: Will be able to tell the test is going to get soap fault as response based on request? Then you can use that as base in your assertion and do conditional check. Then you probably will be able to achieve. Again as @Siking answered, script assertion will have more control in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI will not be able to do what you want out of the box. All assertions you specify have (equivalent of) boolean AND: they all have to pass, to pass the step.

I can see two options to solve your dilemma.

1. Restructure your test case(s), so that you can check the fault separate from the non-fault.
2. You will have to use a Groovy script assertion, do handle your logic.

Possibly something like:

```
def status = messageExchange.responseHeaders["#status#"][0]
if(status.contains("500")) {
    log.info "Fault"
    def faultStr = context.expand( '${#Response#//*:faultstring}' )
    assert faultStr.contains("something special")
} else {
    log.info "Non Fault"
}
```

Your other two assertions, SOAP response and Schema compliance, should apply regardless of fault or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service can return 2 responses then you need to write 2 tests.
1 for the SOAP valid and another for the SOAP fault

Answer (score 0):

I guess this assertions will do the job:

A) response is a valid SOAPResponse:

- Add Assertion -> SoapResponse
- Add Assertion -> Not soapFault

B) response is a SOAPFault with a specific faultstring

- Add Assertion -> SoapFault
- Add Assertion -> XPath Match and configure Xpath Expression related to your faultString and the expected result

Comment: But how will I be able to detect that I'm in one case or the other ?

Comment: well, you can add 2 test steps in your test case . The first one in case of valid soap response and the second in case of the soap fault with you defined faultString.

Comment: Instead of the XPath match I simply use a "contains" validation for the text